# How I can recompile a program with dll extension in R?

Tags: r, shared-libraries, fortran

I created a dll shared library from a fortran77 file using the `g77` compiler. How I can recompile it in R?

Answer (score 1):

Googling for "R build shared library" led me to the [following solution](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/utils/html/SHLIB.html) to your problem. You can use `R CMD SHLIB` to compile shared libraries (dll or so, for windows and linux respectively) for R. See [the documentation](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/utils/html/SHLIB.html) of `R CMD SHLIB` for details.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the options you specified when you created your dll, you may not need to recompile it at all. To load the dll, in R type

```
dyn.load("/path/to/file.dll")
```

and then, if your exported subroutine is `sub`, use

```
.Fortran("sub", ...)
```

to call it.